# neovim: setting syntax highlight popup box?

Tags: neovim, vim-syntax-highlighting

How do I set the foreground and background colors for syntax suggestions in neovim?

[image]

I am executing these commands in my config, which I'm expecting to make the list black and white.

```
vim.cmd('highlight Pmenu ctermfg=white ctermbg=black')
vim.cmd('highlight PmenuSel ctermfg=black ctermbg=white')
vim.cmd('highlight PmenuSbar ctermbg=blue')
vim.cmd('highlight PmenuThumb ctermbg=yellow')
        
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'FloatBorder', {bg='black', fg='white'})
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'NormalFloat', {bg='black'})
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'TelescopeNormal', {bg='black'})
vim.api.nvim_set_hl(0, 'TelescopeBorder', {bg='black'})
```